# Where is the 27th memory?

Tags: opus-rocket-of-whispers

I've finished the game and now trying to get the last memory, but I have no idea where to start looking.

Can someone please help me.

Comment: Could you tell us which memories you already have? I'm fairly sure that memories aren't required to be collected in order, so the 27th memory can be different for different users.

Comment: I have every memory except for one at the bottom which says locked

Comment: The memory below the destination memory is locked

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is it? I tried walking around past the time that the ghosts keep bugging you (approx 22:30). John passes out and you get a short scene afterwards.